# How do I find out if I have a swap partition on my hard drive?

Tags: swap, memory, disk-utility

I used the 12.04 live cd to install Ubuntu over my Windows 7 partition and deleted everything so I just have Ubuntu on my laptop. But since during the installer I chose the simple "erase entire disk" option, did the installer create a swap partition or is that something I should've done with the "something else" option? Btw I have 6GB of RAM

Comment: run `cat /proc/swaps` OR `swapon -s`, It will list the swap partition and swap file which is being used.

Comment: @luv.preet - [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/696234/226614) answer shows that.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

#### Easy, graphical way to check with Disk Utility

1. Open Disk Utility from the Dash:

   [image]
2. In the left column, look for the words "Hard Disk", and click on that:

   [image]
3. In the right column, see if you can find "Swap" as shown. If so, you have swap enabled; you can click on that portion to see details. It will look something like this:

   [image]

---

Alternately, open a terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T`, and type `swapon -s`; if you see a line like the below, with statistics, swap is enabled:

[image]

Comment: `swapon -s` is the easiest way if you didn't set up the computer so you're not sure where the swap would be located (or if it uses a swap *file* instead of a swap partition, or swap on a different drive, swap in compressed RAM, etc).

Comment: `swapon -s` is now deprecated in favor of `swapon --show` [[source](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/swapon.8.html)]

Comment: It appears that `cat /proc/swaps` is the perennial way of doing this, see answer below.

Answer (score 42):

In terminal, type:

```
free -m
```

If you happen to have swap, you will see how much swap memory you have left.

Comment: `free -mh` will make it human readable

Comment: This is incorrect, because `free -m` will only show the presence of swap at all; it won't show whether it's a swap file or swap partition.

Answer (score 27):

Use

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

In addition to the size, it will tell the type of swap (partition/file).
It appears to give exactly the same output as `swapon -s` (posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/159792/226614), but apparently [deprecated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159783/how-do-i-find-out-if-i-have-a-swap-partition-on-my-hard-drive/696234#comment1560823_159792)).

Or

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

which will not give you the correct info in the (unusual) case of a swap added manually, as per comment by Carlo Wood.

Comment: The info in /etc/fstab is neither a guarantee nor always available. That file is used to configure a swap during boot and/or running `swapon -a`, but if you added a swap manually then it won't necessarily be in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @CarloWood - Good to know. So you say `cat /proc/swaps` is reliable in those cases that `cat /etc/fstab` is not?

Comment: Yes - I had an empty `/etc/fstab`, but `/proc/swaps` still showed me the swap that I just added manually.

Comment: `/proc/swaps` shows nothing, `free -m` shows swap 0, `df` shows nothing,'blkid` shows `/dev/sda2` `lsblk -o name,fstype,size` shows `swap 5 G /dev/sda2`. So I have `swap` but a hidden one? When I do `systemctl hibernate` I get `Failed to hibernate system via logind: Not enough swap space for hibernation`. What can I do? `cat /proc/meminfo` shows 6 GB of RAM. Is 1 GB of swap space missing?

Answer (score 12):

I'd use this method to verify presence of a swap partition

Open a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type

```
    sudo blkid | grep swap
```

If you see an entry with `TYPE="swap"`, be sure that, you have a swap partition.

My output is like below: You can see that `/dev/sda7` is a swap partition.

```
/dev/sda7: UUID="4656a2a6-4de0-417b-9d08-c4a5b807f8dd" TYPE="swap"
```

[image]

The Installer should create a swap partition automatically. And also note that, You may never need a swap partition, unless you use "Hibernation" feature or use many more applications at a time. You can check these interesting question about swap size

> [I have 16GB RAM. Do I need 32GB swap?](https://askubuntu.com/q/49109/61218)
>
> [what is SWAP and how large a swap partition should I create?](https://askubuntu.com/q/114566/61218)

If it happens that, You did not create a swap partition, check this question for a help

> [How do I create a swap partition for hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/84318/61218)

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/adding-swap-partition-after-system-installation and (for a swap file in case we can't partition) http://askubuntu.com/questions/126018/adding-a-new-swap-file-how-to-edit-fstab-to-enable-swap-after-reboot

Comment: As Anwar Shah mentioned, this can show you whether you have a partition designated as swap, but this doesn't mean you're using it. Doing this to find swap partitions and verifying with idx's suggestion of 'swapon -s' that they match would be a great solution.

Answer (score 4):

Do `lsblk` and check for SWAP near the end.

In simple terms, `lsblk | grep SWAP`
output:

```
├─sdb2   8:18   0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
```

If you're not familiar with `lsblk`,  `lsblk` lists partitions , their mountpoint, their size etc.

Comment: Can you explain this a little better?  Not everyone is familiar with terminal commands.  It might benefit others if you explain what this means.  For example, what is `lsblk`, and what does it do? What does the output mean? Things like that :)

Comment: On debian I had to `lsblk -o fstype, size` to show `swap`.

Comment: @AnotherKiwiGuy, `man lsblk` will give you a starting kick in.

Answer (score 1):

Open gparted in a terminal:

`sudo gparted`

It will show all the partitions, you can see if you have a swap or not.
You will also be able to 'swapon' or 'swapoff' with gparted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `gparted` as told in the previous post to see all the partitions including swap on your system. `gparted` comes along with the LiveCD but you'll need to install it if you're not using the LiveCD. The command to do that is

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Alternatively, you could also use `sudo fdisk -l` from the terminal to take a look at all the partitions.

```
nits@nits-excalibur:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x27edc0d3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   188743679    94268416    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       224569342   976771071   376100865    5  Extended
/dev/sda4       188743680   224567295    17911808   83  Linux
/dev/sda5       224569344   434284543   104857600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       434286592   644001791   104857600   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       644003840   684001279    19998720   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       684003328   704002047     9999360   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       804003840   972767231    84381696   83  Linux
/dev/sda10      704004096   744001535    19998720   83  Linux
/dev/sda11      744003584   803987455    29991936   83  Linux
/dev/sda12      972769280   976771071     2000896   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

The line stating the FileSystem type as *Linux Swap/ Solaris* is the Swap partition *(in my case the last line)*. You could also peek into your `/etc/fstab` file to see if swap is enabled by default on boot. If it was created during installation, you'll almost always find it here.

```
nits@nits-excalibur:~$ cat /etc/fstab | grep -i swap
# swap was on /dev/sda12 during installation
UUID=5604929a-9d9e-4ab0-907f-b9479a3b55e5 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: with lubuntu 18.04.1, `sudo fdisk -l` did NOT show swap partition, `swapon --show` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The default install creates a SWAP partition, Open system monitor from dash home and resources tab as an alternate way to verify. Something else allows you to do more extensive partitioning if desired.