# How to verify Swap area functioning?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, security, swap

After increasing the Swap area and RAM size,  the `/dev/sda2` has become the Swap area and there is change in the UUID of swap.  When the Ubuntu icon appears first after booting, a long line shows some UUID number for half a second and disappears as if there is some error. But I can access the OS.  How can I verify if there is error or the File system has accepted the new Swap area?  I have noted the UUID of old Swap area. See also:

[Increasing of RAM size & Swap area](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/256227)

```
madhu@madhu-desktop:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=   (Is same)                 ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID= (Starts in 7 and ends in 5)        none            swap    sw              0       0

madhu@madhu-desktop:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
```

Comment: Once you login after restart, you can use our very own `top` cmd to check if new swap has been set and displayed!

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159783/how-do-i-find-out-if-i-have-a-swap-partition-on-my-hard-drive

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following commands from a terminal:

`swapon -s` displays swap devices and sizes
`cat /proc/meminfo` displays the total swap, and the free swap space
`cat /proc/swaps` displays which swap devices are in use

Comment: A good answer. First and the Third command showed the same head only -- Type Size Used Priority. cat /proc/meminfo showed the three items as 0kB viz., SwapCached, SwapTotal, SwapFree. How can I fix the error?

Comment: Could you please edit your question with the output of. `cat /etc/fstab` and `swapon -s`?

Comment: This space doesn't allow me to use more letters. (So some lines only)   UUID= same                ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=Starts with 7 and ends with 5 none            swap    sw              0       0
madhu@madhu-desktop:~$ swapon -s
Filename    Type  Size Used Priority

Comment: There was no data under the last one.

Comment: Click the `edit` button under your question post and add the requested information there please.

Comment: Change the UUID in the last line of the `/etc/fstab` to the one of your current swap partition then restart or execute `mount -a`.

Answer (score 1):

Once the system has booted use the command:

```
swapon --show
```

This will display which partitions have swap enabled.

If you want to find the UUID of a partition of swap type:

```
sudo blkid | grep swap
```

Comment: The word 'swap' is written in red letters (for the second command)

Answer (score 0):

Verify the Swap area data using the following Terminal commands one by one.

```
swapon -s 
cat /proc/meminfo 
cat /proc/swaps
```

Then use the following commands one by one.

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

The UUID of Swap area may be different. Edit the UUID of the Swap area in gedit so that the UUID when installed should match the new Swap area. Save it.

This fixes the error.

Comment: The Swap area was /dev/sda5. But after deleting sda2 Extended & sda5 Linux swap, the Swap area became sda2.  Is it good?  If not, how can I change it?